# Как сериализовать класс в котором есть Dictionary<string,string> в XLM file

Tags: c#, xml, классы, словари, сериализация

Как сериализовать класс в xml file, если в этом классе есть словарь `Dictionary<string string> translator`?
Вот этот класс:

```
      [Serializable]
      public class Translator
      {
         public string VocabularyName { get; set; }
         public Dictionary<string, string> translator = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      }
```

Остальные методы оставил за кулисой.
Нужно два метода, чтение и запись в файл.

Comment: а в чем проблема?

Comment: моя лапша не работает

Comment: Нужен просто код метода, который записывал бы этот класс в xml файл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мой сниппет из проектов

```
public static T SerializeToFile<T>(this T data, string filename)
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        ser.Serialize(sw, data);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Наверное, стоит указать, что это экстеншн, куда его воткнуть, и как использовать. И чисто ради интереса, а зачем здесь возвращаемое значение?

Comment: @aepot автору надо только скопировать тело функции, потому я не стал пояснить ничего. Возвращаемое значение для выстраивания цепочек вызовов, типа fluent interface, в данном случае не является обязательным.

Comment: Понял, про цепочки не подумал, спасибо.

Comment: `XmlSerializer` не умеет (де)сериализовать `Dictionary`.